# Sencha Touch Passcode

Tags: sencha-touch

Is there a control in Sencha Touch to show a passcode field like shown in picture below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No theres no native component who does exactly this. But you can build it by yourself: its a form with 4 input fields and a dozen buttons. See documentation for more details: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.form.FormPanel

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to build and design this one completly by yourself.

Note: To get rid of the browser controls, you have to enforce that the application is running form the homescreen. You can control (with some Javascript) if the application is running MobileSafari or as a "Web App". (see: http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen as an example of such an implementation)

But, however, I would not recommend using such a component. A) This can confuse people and B) Can intent users to type in their regular passcode. As a developer I wouldn't be comfortable with that situation.